# Meaning of "study" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

> The children studied him impassively.

That was an example sentence from a dictionary. Unfortunately I failed to understand its meaning. Besides, there is no more context. This is the whole shebang! To the best of my knowledge, people don't study **someone**, but something! Or maybe everyone else have done that and it's only me who have missed out on the fun!

Comment: Studied means `observed` or `watched` in this context.

Comment: I think you will find that questions of this sort are readily answered with a good dictionary, such as the [Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/study_2); look at definition 2. If that leaves you in any doubt, you may click on the *edit* link above to revise your question, citing what you find in the dictionary and addressing more specific issues.

Comment: @StoneyB- In OALD, definition 2 of study talks about studying something and not someone, as already pointed by the OP

Comment: @StoneyB Thank you. Indeed I look unknown words up in dictionaries before I asked them here. This way life is easier for me too. I ignored that definition because as Ramit mentioned it says "something". However, now I see that they have hidden a "somebody/something" inside the definition!

Comment: @user814064 Thank you. You could write it as an Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One definition from the Free Online Dictionary is "To examine closely; scrutinize."  That's what you do when you study someone.

Answer (score -2):

The Merriam Webster dictionary lists one definition of "studied" to be **carefully considered or prepared, thoughtful**.

In the context you give, it simply means they are carefully, thoughtfully observing him.

It is actually a fairly common usage of this phrase.

Comment: The definition you cite is not relevant to OP's question. Your definition is for *studied* used as an adjective, for example in "a studied position on the issue".